# Excel 2013 files are opening too slowly — what is "Linking: Mobil.XLS"?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

When I open files (simple files without excessive formatting) they are very slow to open. When the new file is being opened, Excel says **"Linking: Mobil.XLS"** or **"linking: EREC summary"** amongst a few others. It may take up to 3 to 4 mins for the file to open.

[image]

I fail to understand how in any way that these files are linked to my file. Is there a way to get rid of the links? Office 2010 is way faster in opening the same file.

Facts:

- These are files copied from a network server to a local PC and then opened.
- They are not password protected.
- They do not have excessive formatting or formulas (simple text).
- I'm using Windows 7, with recently upgraded Office 2013
- The hardware acceleration is removed - so no more lag coming from animation stuff.

I couldn't observe similar issues before the upgrade from 2010 to 2013.

Comment: Does starting Excel in Safe Mode cause it to work faster? Hold `Ctrl` whilst launching Excel and press Yes. Try opening the file again. This will troubleshoot if it's caused by an add-on.

Comment: Hi TeknoVenus, When i open these files, there is a session of excel already open. I will try the Safe mode though.

Comment: Hi TeknoVenus, Tried that without any luck.If there is any other way in which Excel can be forced to not open "links" with any other file, I think we will have a "quick open" of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.
Under the **Formulas tab** locate the **Name manager** and open **Name manager dialog**
In the **Name Manager dialog** under the "Refers to" column locate the "Names" which have access to servers (starting with \\ABC\ etc).
Delete which ever "Names" are not relevant to your file.

Comment: you should mark this answer correct to remove the question from the unanswered queue