# Unable to insert rows or columns in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Office 2013 on Windows 7. Few times, I have not been able to insert rows / columns in a some of the Excel spreadsheets. I tried the following before searching on the internet.

1. Use right-click on the column border to select "Insert" option - the
   option is not grayed out - but it does no action - no rows/columns inserted
2. Click on the "Insert" icon (which is under the "Cells" group of the
   "Home" tab) - select the "Insert sheet rows / Insert sheet columns"
   option from the sub-menu - nothing happens
3. Tried using a keyboard shortcut
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to add rows / columns
   after selecting a particular column or row - no rows/columns
   inserted.

When I googled, I found lot of search results pointing to the error **What does 'To prevent possible loss of data, Excel cannot shift nonblank cells off of the worksheet" mean?** But I'm not getting any such error message when I attempt the insertion of row / column.
There are no patterns of files for which this row/column insert operation fails. Sometimes, it happens to a file on a network server or sometimes to the files on my PC.

The present workaround is to restart Excel and most times it allows row/column insertion on the same file. Has anyone come across similar issues? Any fixes found so far?

Comment: Sounds like you need to reinstall office.

Comment: Are these worksheets protected?

Comment: @jbarker2160 - the worksheets are not protected. They are normal worksheets

Comment: @Raystafarian - I'm wondering how much re-installing Office 2013 would help. Because there seems to be lot of issues with this version of Office. See my other question.... http://superuser.com/questions/784661/excel-2013-files-are-opening-too-slowly-what-is-linking-mobil-xls

Comment: Try Compatibility mode? I'm using Office 2010 so I don't know about version 2013 but already in 2010 there are a lot of terrible bugs that make it totally unusable for me in Word and Excel. I only use Powerpoint in non-compatibility mode but there are scrolling bugs there which can't be fixed at all.

Comment: does any of the solution listed here worked for your case?

Answer (score 4):

I am using Office 2013 Pro Plus and I have also lost my "Insert" option and even "Cut" option along with that.
To overcome that, go to following file path:

```
C:\Users\(user ID)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\Excel15.xlb
```

rename `Excel15.xlb` file to `Excel15.db`.

P.S : Keep Excel off while change.

Comment: What does this do? Does it affect any other feature when when rename this file?

Comment: Two people noted in now deleted answers that this did indeed work. But indeed, it would be really nice to know *why*.

Comment: I'd love to try this but I've been disallowed access to that directory. Any other workarounds?

Comment: This worked! but how and why

Answer (score 2):

The "Cannot shift objects off worksheet" message occurs when you attempt to insert rows or columns in a worksheet, and the option Nothing (hide objects) is selected under the For objects, show section in the Excel Options dialog box. This is a known bug in Microsoft Office Excel 2007. Although this option is not selected by default, it's possible to set it accidentally by pressing a particular keyboard shortcut (CTRL+6).

To work around the bug, you must change the setting from Nothing (hide objects) to All. The fastest way to do this is by pressing CTRL+6.

Alternatively, you can change the setting in the Excel Options dialog box. To do so, click the Microsoft Office Button , and then click Excel Options. On the Advanced tab, scroll to Display options for this workbook settings. Under For objects, show, select All instead of Nothing (hide objects).

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The question is for Excel 2013 not Excel 2007 as referred to in your answer.

Comment: It fixed it for me using 2016...

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel -2013 - Adding a Column or Row - Problem

- File-> Options
- Click on 'Customize Ribbon'
- Click 'New Tab', Rename if you want, Say 'X'.   Click 'Insert Sheet
  Columns'. This action will add this to 'New Tab' created.
- Click 'Insert Sheet Rows'. This action will add this to 'New Tab'
  created.
- Click 'Close'.
- Select any Column.
- You will see a new tab, 'X'.
- Click on 'Insert Sheet Columns', from the new tab 'X'.

This will Add a Ribbon on the top to help you in inserting a row or column, alternate to Right click to add a row or column. Not fixing the issue. Just a workaround.

Comment: Amit, I do not want to have a new tab for for inserting rows and columns. The normal right click insert row or insert column is not working sometimes

Comment: This worked for me, I inherited a sheet that I couldn't insert rows into and this resolved that.