# Excel: Can I find out what external files reference my current workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, links

I am updating a very old excel workbook which may or may not be referenced by other external files and macros.  Is there any way I can trace which files these might be?

I am NOT trying to find out what external files my workbook links to (so the Edit Links function isn't useful, and neither is searching for square brackets in formulae in my current workbook) but the other way around.  Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance
V

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to loop through all the other books and check for references to this one. Or just rename it and wait for things to break. But no, that's not something excel can do. Maybe a different program though.

Comment: @Raystafarian lol Renaming and waiting for things to break doesn't seem like a good option.. even though I don't know of a better way either..

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't any way to check of which workbooks are currently referencing the current workbook. Think of excel simply as a database. The other workbooks are referencing it in a read only type state.

An alternative is if you have suspect workbooks, you can search to see which external workbooks they are referencing.  To do this, click

```
Home > Find & Select > Find. 
Within = Workbook. 
Find what = [
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue of Excel workbooks slowing down due to external links.
I found all the (internal - external) links under the `Name Manager` window.
To navigate to `Name Manager` (I'm using Excel 2010) -> Goto `Defined Names` group under the `Formulas` tab and click the Name manager icon and it will show you the links like this.
[image].

Refer to my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/784661/excel-2013-files-are-opening-too-slowly-what-is-linking-mobil-xls) in superuser if you find that useful.